# i'm trying to understand how asp.net skin works

Tags: asp.net, skin

I've just created a label in default.aspx page and created a skin in skinfile.skin. I've put the skin file in App_Themes folder, i've included the reference to that file in the < link > tag and i've mentioned the skin id for that label.

so according to the code, the label should have background as black and text as orange, right? But nothing's happening. 
What i'm doin wrong here?

Here's the code:

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="App_Themes/SkinFile/SkinFile.skin" />   
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" SkinID="LabelSkin"></asp:Label>
</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

SkinFile.skin:

```
<asp:Label runat="server"  SkinID="LabelSkin" BackColor="Black"    Color="Orange">
</asp:Label>
```

Comment: you don't associate a `.skin` file with a `link` - thats for css.

Comment: oh okay. but even if i remove that, the skin's not getting applied to the label.

Answer (score 0):

i got this thing fixed. all i had to do was set the 'theme' attribute in the <%@ Page.... Theme= "SkinFile" %> statement as the name of the folder in which the skin file is... ^_^